# Read foreign key metadata programatically with Entity Framework 4

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

Does anyone know how one goes about obtaining the schema information out of an edmx generated Entity Framework?

Specifically I want to manage to traverse the foreign key for an entity that I don't currently have an instance of and get the it's foreign key relationships, and I want to do this via reflection in a way that'll be generically applied to any entity class without custom code each time.

EG: My schema has 2 classes, User and Group. I have the number "42" that I know came from the "GroupId" property of a "User" entity, but at the moment I can't work out how to detect that this "GroupId" property of "User" foreign keys to the "Group" entity by it's "GroupId" property.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ended up finding the solution to this. The relevant information can be found in the context's `RelationshipManager` property. By calling `GetAllRelatedEnds()` and then finding the ones of the type `AssociationSet`.

The `ElementType` of the association set then contains an `IsForeignKey` property and also an array `ReferentialConstraints` that has properties for each constraint `ToRole`, `ToProperty`, `FromRole` and `FromProperty` respectively, and the `RelationshipMultiplicity` on the `ToRole`/`FromRole` can be used to determine the direction of the foreign key relationship.

Taking all this data and using the context's `GetObjectByKey` method I was able to programatically traverse the foreign key relationships defined for a context without having the associated entity.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work.  I couldn't find a RelationshipManager property on the context (though I can get it by CType(tableObject, IEntityWithRelationships).RelationshipManager), and then after doing that I couldn't find results from GetRelatedEnds that could be cast to AssociationSet.  A code example would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Hey, apologies for the delayed response - I hadn't read this in a long time. I should have been more clear that I was working from an ObjectStateEntry as opposed to directly from the Context. The exact syntax I used from there was "foreach (AssociationSet assoc in ose.RelationshipManager.GetAllRelatedEnds().Select(end => end.RelationshipSet).Where(rs => rs is AssociationSet && ((AssociationSet)rs).ElementType.IsForeignKey).Cast<AssociationSet>())", then I had some additional logic to work out which side it was on cause I only wanted specific multiplicities of foreign keys.

Answer (score 24):

You can use the following approach --

```
foreach (EntityType entity in ItemCollection.GetItems<EntityType>().OrderBy(e => e.Name))
foreach (var entityMember in entity.NavigationProperties)
foreach (System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EdmProperty foreignKey in entityMember.GetDependentProperties())
{
    //... use foreignKey
}
```

Comment: Excellent - thank you!  I don't know how to get the poster's answer to work, but yours worked the first time.  A+ for the code example too!

Comment: Just great.  Not least because finding relevant information for this stuff on Google is extremely hard.

Comment: This not works in EF6! ItemCollection.GetItems<EntityType> An object reference is required for the no-static field.

Comment: For EF 6, you can see my answer in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35001808/programmatically-obtain-foreign-keys-between-pocos-in-entity-framework-6/35002571#35002571)