# Entity Framework: how to dynamically retrieve DatabaseGeneratedOptions for columns and the foreign key columns for navigation properties?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, code-first

I have a POCO entity as follows:

```
public class Entity {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? OtherEntityId { get; set; }
    public virtual OtherEntity OtherEntity { get; set; }
}
```

The code-first configuration is as follows:

```
conf.HasKey(e => e.Id).ToTable("entities");
conf.Property(e => e.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
conf.HasOptional(e => e.OtherEntity).WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.OtherEntityId);
```

I'd like to be able to retrieve the database generated option & FK properties at runtime. For example, I can dynamically retrieve the primary key property like so:

```
var keyProperties = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<Entity>()
    .EntitySet
    .ElementType
    .KeyMembers
    .Select(km => typeof(Entity).GetProperty(km.Name));
    .ToList()
```

How can I do this (I am using EF 4.3.1)?

Answer (score 2):

For looking up the foreign key properties, just use @Ashraf's answer on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384081/read-foreign-key-metadata-programatically-with-entity-framework-4).

I couldn't find anything similar for finding the DatabaseGenerated attribute while keeping the Fluent API. If you're willing to put a data annotation on your POCO, you should be able to grab it using reflection, just like any other attribute (similar to what's being done on [this blog post](http://blogs.southworks.net/dschenkelman/2012/08/18/creating-indexes-via-data-annotations-with-entity-framework-5-0/)):

```
typeof(Entity).GetProperties().Where(prop => prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (DatabaseGeneratedAttribute), true).Any());
```

This will return an `IEnumerable><PropertyInfo>`, which you should then be able to play around with.