# Programmatically obtain Foreign keys between POCOs in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-keys, poco

I am faced with an EF6 Code First context, with a few `DbSet`s of POCOs that have navigation properties (and foreign keys) between them, e.g.:

```
public partial class Person
{
    public         Guid                 Id      { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Address> Address { get; set; } 
}

public partial class Address
{
    public         Guid   Id          { get; set; }
    public         Guid   FK_PersonId { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person      { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .HasMany            (e => e.Address)
    .WithRequired       (e => e.Person)
    .HasForeignKey      (e => e.FK_PersonId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Given these types, is there any proper way (i.e. without resorting to iterating over the POCO properties/fields by reflection and "guessing") to programmatically determine that `Address` has an `FK_PersonId` pointing to the `Id` property of `Person`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the FK property's names for an specific entity you can use this generic method:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetFKPropertyNames<TEntity>() where TEntity:class
{
        using (var context = new YourContext())
        {
            ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
            ObjectSet<TEntity> set = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>();
            var Fks = set.EntitySet.ElementType.NavigationProperties.SelectMany(n=>n.GetDependentProperties());
            return Fks.Select(fk => fk.Name);
        }
 }
```

And if you want the nav. property's names the only you need to do is this:

```
 //...
 var navProperties = set.EntitySet.ElementType.NavigationProperties.Select(np=>np.Name);
```

Comment: I am getting an error that the type or namespace `TEntity` cannot be found. What type of object is the TEntity supposed to be?

Comment: you need to specify one of the entity type of your model at the time you invoke this method, eg, `GetFKPropertyNames<Person>()`

Comment: This gives me the  property names of the foreign keys, but not the column names of the Fks. I am using Data Annotations  and/or fluent mappings to  define the column names. Any thoughts on how to get the actual column names instead?

Comment: Hi 

i am trying to do similar thing. Problem I have got is, I have entity type not the Entity which I can't use for <TEntity>. Can you please let me know how can I achieve this with entity type. I want to get Navigation property from FK and then can value from the nav property.