# How Do You Determine the Parent Navigation Properties for an Entity Using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-6, parent, navigation-properties

I have an Entity Framework 6 POCO and I want to obtain the list of parent navigation properties for that POCO.  The code below is how far I have gotten.  It seems to work but I can't confirm it will work in all cases.

For example, for POCO Book

```
class Book
{
   int AuthorId;
   int BookId;
        
   virtual Author TheAuthor;
}



// Here I pass in the EntityType for the Book POCO.  
// This should return new List<string> { "TheAuthor"}
public GetParentNavigationProperties(System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EntityType entityType)
{
    
    return entityType.NavigationProperties
    .Where(np => np.GetDependentProperties().Count() > 0)
    .Select(np=>np.Name).ToList(); 
}
```

The code above is in part derived from the following post:      [Programmatically obtain Foreign keys between POCOs in Entity Framework 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35001808/programmatically-obtain-foreign-keys-between-pocos-in-entity-framework-6/35002571#35002571)

Comment: Why are you using reflection? If a book can have multiple authors and you want that list, it would be as simple as `context.Book.Include(b => b.Authors).ToList();` You would need to change Author to ICollection<Author>,

Comment: I am using reflection because I am writing T4 templates that require I know without prior knowledge which properties in an EF POCO are parent navigation properties.